# getting page views by two custom dimensions of different granularity in bigquery

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm trying to pull a report from bigquery where I can see pageviews segmented by day and couple of custom dimensions (one at hit level and the other at session level) with this query:

```
SELECT 
      date
      ,SUM(totals.pageviews) as PVs
      ,MAX(IF(hits.customDimensions.index = 11, hits.customDimensions.value,NULL)) AS x
      ,MAX(IF(customDimensions.index = 1, customDimensions.value,NULL)) AS y

FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([111111111.ga_sessions_]
                     ,TIMESTAMP('2016-10-01')
                     ,TIMESTAMP('2016-10-31')) 

       GROUP EACH BY 1
```

I get the following:

```
Error: Cannot query the cross product of repeated fields customDimensions.index and hits.page.pagePath.
```

I've been looking at other answers but didn't find anything addressing a similar  enough issue. Could you suggest a better query?

Thanks!

Comment: The weird thing is that I just ran this query against our BQ and it worked fine. Just to confirm, could you please re-run the query to see if the error persists? You are not using `hits.page.pagepath` and still the error mentions it which doesn't seem to make much sense as well.

Comment: You'll have an easier time using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) for the query. Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40643254/grouping-and-pivoting-custom-dimensions/40643510#40643510) for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to flatten your data

take a look at Google's example reporting "Cannot query the cross product of repeated fields children.age and citiesLived.yearsLived" within [Dealing with data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data)

"To query across more than one repeated field, you need to flatten one of the fields:

`SELECT
  fullName,
  age,
  gender,
  citiesLived.place
FROM (FLATTEN([dataset.tableId], children))
WHERE
  (citiesLived.yearsLived > 1995) AND
  (children.age > 3)
GROUP BY fullName, age, gender, citiesLived.place`"

to get around the table_date_range limitation, try creating a sub select first

```
SELECT
  hits.eventInfo.eventCategory,
  hits.eventInfo.eventAction,
  customDimensions.value
FROM
  FLATTEN((
    SELECT
      hits.eventInfo.eventCategory,
      hits.eventInfo.eventAction,
      customDimensions.index,
      customDimensions.value
    FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([dataset.table_], DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -3, 'DAY'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'DAY')))),hits.eventInfo.eventCategory)
```

as discussed on [Official Google BigQuery issue and feature request tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=113)

Comment: Yeap, I read that article but was unable to make it work with a date range

Comment: known issue logged with bigquery https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=113  As a workaround, try using the subselect (example put in above)

Comment: They seem to have closed the request now.